# Pandas Window Function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I need a function that returns the average of a specific window of pandas. Let's say our data is in the nth row. My window needs to sum ( n-2, n-1, n, n+1, n+2) and find the average. Pandas has rolling functions but I think it only does that in one direction one not in 2 directions at the same time.

Comment: FYI, `df.rolling` (or that of a Series) has a parameter `center` that you can pass `True`.

Comment: I tried to edit this question to make it easier for people with this same question to find in the future, though the suggested edit queue is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution implements what was described by Neither, using a centered window.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(np.arange(100))
>>> series
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
      ..
95    95
96    96
97    97
98    98
99    99
Length: 100, dtype: int32
>>> series.rolling(5, center=True).mean()
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      2.0
3      3.0
4      4.0
      ...
95    95.0
96    96.0
97    97.0
98     NaN
99     NaN
Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Note that for centered windows of `n` elements, where `n` is odd, the first and last `n // 2` elements will be `NaN`, as they aren't the center of any window.